# trigget and event when model change and change template data, Backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js

Let's say I have some conditions set on a backbonejs template like this:

```
 <% if(model.get(attribute) === true) { %>
      display X
 <% } else { %>
     display Y
 <% { %>
```

All this data comes from a json file, with different objects which into my template are displayed into a _.each()... so, after some front end interaction I set something like.

```
 myCollection.collection.at(0).set('attribute', false);
```

so the question is... can I dinamilly change the front end to "display Y" without reloading the page or calling the controller back???

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

UPDATE

My view looks like this:

```
 myView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: '.main',

     render : function() {
        template = _.template($('#myTemaplte').html(), { models : this.collection.models });
        this.$el.html(template);
     }
 });



 var theCollection = new Collections.myCollection;
 theCollection.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
            myList = new myView({collection : theCollection});
    }
 });
```

and the json file looks like:

```
 data [
  {
   "atribute" : false
  },
  {
   "atribute" : true
  },
  {
   "atribute" : false
  },
 ]
```

Comment: show me your view/controller.

Comment: I dont have access to the API controller, it just returns a json where the attribute I am setting is set to false, and I have nothing else on my View than the template rendering, that's why I did not post it, would it make any different?

Comment: i am asking about your backbone view, may be i can add the logic to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 myView = Backbone.View.extend({
         el: '.main',

         initalize : function(){
         this.listenTo(this.collection,'change',this.render); 
         },
         render : function() {
            template = _.template($('#myTemaplte').html(), { models : this.collection.models });
            this.$el.html(template);
         }
     });
```